# Create validation based on users 'bet' so they can't bet over their 'balance'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The user has a balance (user.balance).

The user can post bets on a game (bet.amount).

How could I stop the user from betting more than what is in their balance?

I assume I could create a validation that looks something like this?

```
def enough_funds?
  @bet.bet_amount > self.current_user.balance 
  flash[:notice] = "You do not have the available funds for this bet"
end
```

I'm still new to rails, be gentle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validate :funds_suffiency

  def funds_sufficiency
    errors.add :bet_amount, "is more than your available balance" if bet_amount < user.balance
  end
end
```

If `Bet`'s `:bet_amount` is less than the related `User`'s available `:balance`, the error will be added to `:bet_amount` attribute, invalidating the model instance.

Comment: Thanks Deefour. That is perfect.